# React-router-dom - Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am building a react app with animated route transitions. Everything seems to work, but the console keeps showing warning from the title.
Below is my render function for routes:

```
render() {
  return (
    <main>
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
        transitionName="app"
        transitionEnterTimeout={600}
        transitionLeaveTimeout={600}
      >
        <Switch key={location.pathname} location={location}>
          <Route path="/route1" component={Route1} />
          <Route path="/route2" component={Route2} />
          <Route path="/route3" component={Route3} />
          <Redirect to="/route1" />
        </Switch>
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    </main>
  );
}
```

I have 3 routes, everything else should redirect to /route1. If I manually enter /route4 in url bar, the warning appears.

If I remove ReactCSSTransitionGroup the warning disappears.

```
render() {
  return (
    <main>
      <Switch key={location.pathname} location={location}>
        <Route path="/route1" component={Route1} />
        <Route path="/route2" component={Route2} />
        <Route path="/route3" component={Route3} />
        <Redirect to="/route1" />
      </Switch>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Since the app works, its not really a big deal. But I prefer to not have warnings in my apps, and I want to keep the transitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A route without a `path` prop will always render.

So if you want to designate `Route1` as a catch-all component, simply remove it's `path` prop.

Of course the `Switch` will display **the first route that matches**, so the catch-all needs to be the last route.

```
<Switch key={location.pathname} location={location}>
    <Route path="/route2" component={Route2} />
    <Route path="/route3" component={Route3} />
    <Route component={Route1} />
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and place the `<Redirect />` above the `<Route />`.

```
render() {
  return (
    <main>
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
        transitionName="app"
        transitionEnterTimeout={600}
        transitionLeaveTimeout={600}
      >
        <Switch key={location.pathname} location={location}>
          <Redirect to="/route1" />
          <Route path="/route1" component={Route1} />
          <Route path="/route2" component={Route2} />
          <Route path="/route3" component={Route3} />
        </Switch>
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    </main>
  );
}
```